# Garbage values when writing and reading to a text file

Tags: c++

Can Some one help me the problem with this code? I am getting bunch of garbage value !

```
fstream fs("hello.txt");

if(fs.is_open())
{    
    string s = "hello";
    string line;
    fs << s;  

    while(getline(fs,line))
    {
        cout << line;
    }
    cin.get();
}
fs.close();
```

Thank you very much but when I try to do this I am getting same garbage. I am trying to rewrite the first hello with world and trying to print that line

```
fstream fs("hello.txt");

if(fs.is_open())
{    
    string s = "hello";
    string line;
    fs << s << endl;  
    fs.seekg(0);
    fs << "world" << endl;
    fs.seekg(0);

    while(getline(fs,line))
    {
        cout<<line;
    }
    cin.get();
}
fs.close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If hello.txt is empty prior to running the program then it seems to work for me. If the file contains more than 6 or 7 characters then your hello world code will overwrite the first 6/7 chars with "world" followed by the line terminator (which might be 1 or 2 chars depending on the platform). The reminder of the file won't be overwritten and will be subsequently printed by your getline loop.

Answer (score 3):

The cursor of `fs` is at the end of file after you `fs << s` (this is required to append data to the file properly).

Try to call `fs.seekg(0);` to move the cursor back to the beginning.

Also, you may need to supply the `fstream::trunc` or `fstream::app` flag when constructing `fs`.

```
fstream fs("hello.txt", fstream::in | fstream::out | fstream::trunc);
```

Comment: Thank you very much but I edited the code as shown in the post. Now I am getting same garbage value.

Comment: @brett: Not reproducible. I got `world` on the screen. (Call `seekg(0)` *only after* you have written everything.)